# DbContext.Database.Mirgate() .. what about rollback?

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

So there is a extension function 
Migrate()

> dbContext.Database.Migrate();

which will apply all pending migrations to the database.

but if one of them fail . how do I roll back last step or last two migrations ?

say I have to apply A,B,C but roll back only B and C 
is this even possible with code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rollback *B* and *C*, simly specify target migration, i.e. *A*:

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
migrator.Update("A");
```

It is like: `Update-Database -TargetMigration A`

Comment: I save LKG (last known good) migration before I apply new ones. If anything wrong, I migrate back to LKG